# jQuery .keyup() with .bind() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery code to trigger a input field by using the enter key. I used the code in another view and it works perfect. In the new view, somehow it doesn't work at all. The keyup gets triggered but the `.bind()` function is not called.
Here's the HTML trigger:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <h3>Customers</h3>
   <input class="form-control" id="searchNew" placeholder="Search" name="searchNew" autofocus="" value="@form("searchValue").value">
</div>
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$('#searchNew').bind("enterKey", function(e){
    console.log("Test2");
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.loading').fadeIn();
        },
        complete:function(){
            $('.loading').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '@routes.Application.searchLicensesAdmin()',
        data : $('#search').serialize(),
        success : function (data) {
            $('#license-table').html(data);
            return false;
        },
        error : function (data) {
            console.log("Error");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
$('#searchNew').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        console.log("Test1");
        $(this).on("enterKey");
    }
});
```

Test1 gets triggered and shows up in the console, but Test2 is not even triggered at all. So the problem is not the `ajax` call, but the `.bind()`. It's probably a stupid reason why it doesn't work but i can't figure it out. jQuery is included in both documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need `$(this).trigger('enterKey')`.

`.bind()` and `.on()` do pretty much the same, although `.bind()` is deprecated as of version 3 (so don't use it ;)).

The statement `$(this).on('enterKey')` just registers a new event listener, with an empty / undefined callback

Answer (score 2):

You want to *trigger* the custom event

Change

```
$(this).on("enterKey");
```

To

```
$(this).trigger("enterKey");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
$(this).trigger("enterKey");
```

it is not recommended to use .bind() as it is deprecated.